# Prove that a permutation is a $p$-cycle

Tags: symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

I have difficulties proving the following theorem:

Let $σ ∈ S_n$ satisfy $σ \neq (1)$, and $σ^p = (1)$, where p is a prime number such that $\frac{n}{2} < p ≤ n$. 
Prove that σ is a p-cycle.

There are many similar questions here, however they are all slightly different from this theorem. Obviously, if $\sigma$ is a p-cycle, then $σ^p = (1)$, but I'm not sure how to use  $\frac{n}{2} < p ≤ n$ to prove that no other length of the cycle is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the elements of $S_n$ of order $p$ for any prime $p \leq n$? Are they not the product of finitely many distinct $p$ cycles?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Dbchatto67 I would say so, as $\sigma^p=(1)$ and for any integer $a$ with $\sigma^a=(1)$ we must have $ord(\sigma)|a$. As p is prime, and $p>1$, we must have $p=ord(\sigma)$. How do you conclude that if $ord(\sigma)=p$, then $\sigma$ is a p-cycle?

Comment: I have said that if $\sigma \in S_n$ is of order $p$ then it is the product of finitely many distinct $p$-cycles if no further constraints are assumed. In this case since $p > \frac n 2$ there cannot be more than one distinct $p$-cycle in $S_n.$ Hence in this case $\text {ord}\ (\sigma) = p \implies \sigma$ should be a $p$-cycle.

Comment: Remember that every permutation can be written in disjoint cycle notation. What are the cycle lengths that are possible here? How many disjoint cycles can you have, given that the permutation is in $S_n$?

Comment: I would be interested to have a full answer here.